# How to compile C++ REST SDK into a static library on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: c++, rest, sdk, static-libraries

I want to compile C++ REST SDK (https://casablanca.codeplex.com/) into a static library on Ubuntu. Has anyone done it? How to do it? Their documentation only shows how to create a dynamic library for Ubuntu but no static.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create the static library, follow the same instructions as to create a shared library but append `"-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=0"` to the cmake configure line.